# Как проверить на наличие id в nosql базе?

Tags: sql, nosql

Моя задача: взять id посетителей и определить были ли у них проходы по территории за промежуток времени.
Я сделал так:

```sql
from "event"
group by Payload.identifiers.subject_id
where Payload.identifiers.subject_id != null
and Payload.time_stamp between 10.12.2021 and 10.12.2022
and Payload.identifiers.subject_id in ("90571ff8-47b2-416a-91a9-98bdb15e8606")
select Payload.identifiers.subject_id as PayloadId, count(Lines[].Quantity) as Count
```

потом я у себя в коде проверяю на `count`. Т.е если count > 0, то я возвращаю id

Мне кажется, что это не совсем оптимально при миллионах записей. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать?

Comment: `sql` и `nosql` - как эти метки могут сочетаться?..

Comment: Как много ответов вы получили на этот вопрос... А всё почему? Указывайте то, что используете: язык программирования, СУБД, фреймворк, библиотеку. Причём **точные** версии!